# Passing DateTime data from Django to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to pass data (step_count_data) from Django to a JavaScript function.
Here are the code:

Django

```
#somecode
step_count_date.append(str(step_count_list[i].startTime.date()))

        context = {'step_count_date': json.dumps(step_count_date)}
        return render_to_response('patient-profile.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Javascript:

```
step_from_django = JSON.parse({{ step_count_date }})
console.log(step_from_django);
```

However I got an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
and the error line is

```
step_from_django = JSON.parse([&quot;2015-03-19&quot;, &quot;2015-04-02&quot;])
```

What I want is just the date without the " wrap around.
Any idea why and how can I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
step_from_django = JSON.parse({{ step_count_date|safe }});
```

or simply like this:

```
step_from_django = {{ step_count_date|safe }};
```